# C++ Casting a byte binary value into a string

Tags: c++

How do I convert 6 bytes representing a MAC address into a string that displays the address as colon-separated hex values?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want in the resulting string?  Do you want a textual representation of the bytes (e.g. hex) or do you want to actually interpret the 6 bytes as ASCII (or some other encoding)?

Comment: I am looking to get the textual representation, so yes hex.

Comment: Or is it a 48-bit number? If so, what encoding is it in, and what's the endian-ness?

Comment: Improve your question, please. We are not mind readers - the more information give, the better the response will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want a sequence of six bytes to be formatted like so:

```
aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

where `aa` is the first byte formatted in hex.

Something like this should do:

```
char MAC[6]; //< I am assuming this has real content

std::ostringstream ss;
for (int i=0; i<6; ++i) {
    if (i != 0) ss << ':';
    ss.width(2); //< Use two chars for each byte
    ss.fill('0'); //< Fill up with '0' if the number is only one hexadecimal digit
    ss << std::hex << (int)(MAC[i]);
}

return ss.str();
```

If you dearly want to do this in a cast-like style (guessing from your title here), you can create a MAC class, implement the ostream-operator for it (like my given code) and use `boost::lexical_cast`.

Comment: Looks like you got there first :)

Comment: I already had a cast.h and added this and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you mean cast or convert. If convert, then it depends in what form you want it. You might want Hex, base-64, octal, ...

If you want hex, consider [STLSoft](http://www.stlsoft.org/)'s [`format_bytes()`](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/byte__format__functions_8hpp.html) function, which can do all kinds of ordering and grouping.

If you want base-64, consider the [b64 library](http://www.synesis.com.au/software/b64.html).

HTH

[EDIT] In line with the edit on the OP, the full impl would be:

```
#include <stlsoft/conversion/byte_format_functions.hpp>

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char mac[6];

    char result[STLSOFT_NUM_ELEMENTS(mac) * 3];

    stlsoft::format_bytes(mac, sizeof(mac), &result[0], STLSOFT_NUM_ELEMENTS(result), 1, ":");

    puts(result);

    return 0;
}
```

There's no need *in this case* to check the return value from `format_bytes()` because you're passing in enough write buffer. In a real case you'd want to check

Answer (score 1):

1. *Make sure it is null terminated*
2. You need to know what encoding the string is in. If it's ASCII, a simple std::string str((char*) your_buffer) will do. your_buffer should be an unsigned char. If it's not, we need more info.

Comment: If it's not null terminated, you can use std::string's assign() method, which optionally takes two additional arguments of starting position and number of characters, e.g. std::string str; str.assign(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), 0, 6);

Comment: The input is a 6byte binary value that is supplied to me from the Net-SNMP library and all I need is the hex value it returns as it is a MAC address.

Comment: I added this info to your question, since it was not at all clear that that's what you wanted to do.